# Finding solution to Mv=v over $\mathbb{Z}$={0,1} for matrix M given a set linearly independent v

Tags: arithmetic, linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Under mod 2 arithmetic ($\mathbb{Z}$={0,1}), given a set $V$ of $n$x$1$ linearly independent vectors $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ I'd like to find a $n^2$ binary matrix $M$ such that $Mv=v$ where $v \in V$ and $M\bar{v}\neq \bar{v}$ for $\bar{v}\not \in  V$.

I supposed it would also be helpful to know the technical term for a matrix that acts as an identity exclusively for given set of vectors when multiplied by any member of that set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.  Such matrices don't exist.  We always have $Mv=v$ whenever $v=0$ (the all-zeros vector).  No set that contains the all-zeros vector is linearly independent, so surely $0 \notin V$.  Therefore, no matter what $M$ you choose, when we set $v=0$, we discover $Mv=v$ for some $v \notin V$, which violates your requirements. In other words, no matrix $M$ can satisfy the requirements.

Another proof of impossibility: suppose $u,v \in V$; if $Mu=u$ and $Mv=v$, then by linearity $M(u+v)=(u+v)$, but by linear independence, $u+v \notin V$.

Or, to put it another way, the kernel of a matrix/linear map is always a linear subspace.

Comment: "`no set that contains the all-zeros vector is linearly independent`" Doesn't specifying  that V consist of linearly independent vectors avoid the v=0 case?  Consider the trivial case of an M as the identity matrix over all possible linearly independent binary vectors of length 2: ((1,0),(0,1)) for the set {(1,0), (0,1), (1,1)}

Comment: @JamesBowery, see edited answer.  I suggest you try to work through a simple example.  If $V=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, then $M=$ identity matrix does *not* meet the requirements.  When $v=(0,0)$, then $Mv=v$, but $v \notin V$.  Your requirements require that when $v \notin V$, we must have $Mv\ne v$.  So the identity matrix does not comply with your requirements, in that situation.

Comment: I see now that I should have specified that all vectors must be non-null -- not that the given set of vectors is non-null (due to their being linearly independent). 

If it is within the etiquette of cs.stackexchange to do so I'll accept your answer and post another one that is better specified.  Otherwise I'll edit this one to so-specify non-null vectors.

Comment: @JamesBowery, Thanks.  Normally we discourage changing the question to invalidate existing answers, but in this case, either way is fine with me.  *However*, I suggest you work through an example in a bit more detail; and read the second paragraph of my answer carefully, which I think already answers your planned revised question.

Comment: Recognizing that I have at least one error and one omission in my specification, I'll just accept your answer and go do some more homework.  Thanks!